# Trying to flash h3-tag after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script on my website that scrolls down to given areas of the page when clicking a link nicely using the following code:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 800);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This, combined with the use of this HTML

```
<a href="#thinig">Go to the thing!</a>
<a href="#thinig2">Go to the  other thing!</a>

<div id="thing">
    <h3>A new title</h3>
    <p>Thing is here<p>
</div>

<div id="thing2">
    <h3>The other stuff title</h3>
    <p>Thing two is here<p>
</div>
```

scrolls down to the "thing" div quite nicely, and works as intended. However, I would like the -tag to blink once in a different color than the default color of text when the user reaches the content, after clicking and being scrolled down. How can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to use the 'complete' callback from animate:

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
 $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 800,function(){
                     //highlight here   
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the "highlight" effect of jquery [highlight example](http://api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect/) or you use the pulsate effect [pulsate here](http://api.jqueryui.com/pulsate-effect/)

code would look like this:

HTML

```
<a href="#thinig">Go to the thing!</a>

<div id="thing">
    <h3>A new title</h3>
    <p>Thing is here<p>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 800, function(){
            $('#thing').effect( "highlight", 
                  {color:"#669966"}, 3000 );
        });
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css3 transition and keyframes on adding class with js and then remove class after animation done (removeclass with setTimeout on same duration with css transition).